# How can I retrieve all mouse coordinates between mousedown to mouseup event

Tags: javascript, jquery

As per the jQuery docs below code can be used to capture mouseup and mouse down events.  But my requirement is bit different

```
$("#dic").mouseup(function () {

}).mousedown(function () {

});
```

But How can I calculate mouse moving co-ordinates between mousedown position to mouseup position. Please help me on this. How can I apply mousemove event between mousedown and mouseup

Comment: Do you need all coordinates between these events or just the two?

Comment: So which is it?  Just the two, or all?

Comment: @apsillers I want to retrieve all the mouse moved co-ordinates from mousedown to mouseup events...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to captue all points the mouse moves through during a drag, bind/unbind a new `mousemove` handler:

```
var allPoints = [];
$("#dic").mouseup(function (e) {
    $(this).unbind("mousemove", trackPoints);
}).mousedown(function (e) {
    $(this).bind("mousemove", trackPoints); 
});

function trackPoints(e) {
    allPoints.push({ x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY });
}
```

This way, `trackPoints` will start firing when the mouse is down and stop when it goes back up.

You may also want to add a `if(e.which == 1)` to the top of your `mouseup` and `mousedown` handlers so that they perform the `bind` for a left mouse button only, not middle or right buttons.

Answer (score 4):

```
var X = [],
    Y = [],
    i = -1;
$("#dic").mouseup(function(e) {
    ++i;
    X[i] = e.pageX;
    Y[i] = e.pageY;
    // reset everything on mouseup
    X = [];
    Y = [];
    i = -1;
}).mousedown(function(e) {
    ++i;
    X[i] = e.pageX;
    Y[i] = e.pageY;
    console.log(X);
}).mousemove(function(e) {
    ++i;
    X[i] = e.pageX;
    Y[i] = e.pageY;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/guSpj/4/)**

Comment: It will give me only mouseup and mousedown co-ordinates.. But I need all the co-ordinates...

Comment: @SoI check the demo and console also

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = [], y = [], i = 0;

$("#dic").mouseup(function (e) {
    $('#status').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY + ' up');
    x[i] = e.pageX;
    y[i++] = e.pageY;

    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
});

$("#dic").mousedown(function (e) {
    $('#status').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY + ' down');
    i = 0;
    x[i] = e.pageX;
    y[i++] = e.pageY;
});

$("#dic").mousemove(function (e) {
    $('#status').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY + ' move');
    x[i] = e.pageX;
    y[i++] = e.pageY;
});
```

This will begin recording mouse positions on mousedown and you can see the output on the console on mouseup. Then you can calculate the distance as thecodeparadox described with the first and last items of the arrays, or any other points in between the start and end.

[Code on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PJ6P2/2/)

Comment: It gives me all the mouse moved co-ordinates.. But I need between only mouse down to up events....

Comment: Yeah, the mousemove will continue to add to the array. If you don't want it to do that, you can unbind the mousemove event in the mouseup code and bind it again on mousedown. Although, the way I have presented it, when it logs the arrays to the console, you have the first coordinate (mousedown), all mousemove coordinates, and the final coordinate (mouseup) in the arrays. If you don't want the first and last, take out the x[i] and y[i++] lines in mouseup and mousedown to only get the in-between-movements.

edit: just realized apsillers's answer does exactly that.