# Capture all mouse coordinates while mousedown

Tags: javascript, html

How can I capture all the coordinates the mouse moved through in mousedown event using plain javascript?

```
var my_canvas=document.getElementById("drawing-pad");
var ctx=my_canvas.getContext("2d");
my_canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", draw_on_click, false);

function draw_on_click(e){
    var x_pos=e.clientX;
    var y_pos=e.clientY;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(x_pos,y_pos,15,15);
}
```

I was expecting the handler to run on every coordinates (would be nice if it would!) but I was wrong.

I saw the answer similar to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836538/how-can-i-retrieve-all-mouse-coordinates-between-mousedown-to-mouseup-event) in SO but it uses Jquery and I am trying to stay away from it because I want to start on using Angular after gaining some more proficiency in core and client javascript.

**Thoughts:** One thing comes to mind. Should I use setInterval inside the handler and capture clientX and clientY periodically and clear it out when mouseup event happens? Am I thinking it right? Is there better way to do this?

Comment: @Nit: How can you even not read the question full to point out duplicate? I specifically indicated that there was answer using Jquery.

Comment: The method through which the problem is solved is identical, you simply need to bind events using vanilla Javascript, not jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need 3 event handlers**

if mousedown set ismousedown to true. 
if mouseup set ismousedown to false. 
then in mousemove if the mouse is down draw.

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',mousedown,false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousedmove',mousedmove,false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',mouseup,false);
var isMouseDown=false;

function mousedown(){
 isMouseDown=true
}
function mousemove(){
 if(isMouseDown){
  //do stuff
 }
}
function mouseup(){
 isMouseDown=false
}
```

and here is a partially working drawing demo. click on circle rect or draw.
draw&erease is like described above the circle and rect is based on 2 points (2 clicks)

http://jsfiddle.net/k5LUT/

you need to set erease to `c.strokeStyle='hsla(0,0%,0%,0)';` and fill does not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Set a flag when your mouse is down, and capture everything in the mouse move

```
var md = false, x, y;

var draw_on_click = function() {
    md = true;

    //do your thing...
}

var toggle_draw = function() {
    md = false;
}

var on_move = function() {
    if(md) {
        var x_pos=e.clientX;
        var y_pos=e.clientY;
    }    
}

my_canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", draw_on_click, false);
my_canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", toggle_draw, false);
my_canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", on_move, false);
```

EDIT: Just noticed you have a mousedown not click, edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To follow the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10836882/995320) on the question you are refering to, you could do following:

```
my_canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function() { 
    my_canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw_on_click, false); 
}, false);
my_canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    my_canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", draw_on_click, false);
}, false);
```

this would be exactly what the jquery version is doing.

**Note:** that you may need to listen to global `mouseup` if the user is dragging to the outside of the canvas, depends on whats your intention