# calling functions inside functions - Trouble:function not executing

Tags: javascript, function, scope

Ok. I want to apologize first because I don not even know how to title this question properly.
I will try to explain:
I have a working code for this that kind-of-works, but it is a bit messy, so I am trying to divide it into small functions.
The whole process is a simulated scrollbar:

-div id="scrollbar" represents the scrollbar track.
-div id="scrollbar"'s only child represents the scrollbar thumb.

Now. Whenever an "onmousedown" event takes place in document.documentElement, function checkAndPerform(e) gets executed.
checkAndPerform(e) gets borders of scrollbar and calls the following functions:

-checkClick(e): It checks if click has occurred inside scrollbar and returs true or false.

-perform(): If result of checkClick is true, it moves thumb to click position. Also, it scrolls down the section where the scrollbar operates (section id="ejercicios"). Finally, it adds a "mousemove" EventListener to document.documentElement, with function followMe(e) attached to it.
This followMe function calls a function that limits scroll to trackbar borders. After that it perform translation of div and scrolling of section while "mousemove" is active, and finally calls a function release(), that adds a "mouseup" EventListener to remove the followMe function after mouse button gets released.

The idea for the code was got here:

[How can I retrieve all mouse coordinates between mousedown to mouseup event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836538/how-can-i-retrieve-all-mouse-coordinates-between-mousedown-to-mouseup-event), where you can see in accepted answer that function called "trackPoints" gets called troubleless (as it is in my previous code).

So, here it is troubling javascript code:

```
function getHeight(object) {
    var height = object.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - object.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    return height;
}

function checkClick(e) {
    console.log("x:" + e.pageX, "y:" + e.pageY);
    if (e.pageX > sBLeft - 5 && e.pageX < sBRight + 5 && e.pageY < sBBottom && e.pageY > sBTop) {
        adentroBar = true;
        console.log("meas adentro");
    } else {
        adentroBar = false;
        console.log("meas afuera");
    }
    return adentroBar;
}

function scrollLimited(e) {
    if (e.pageY < sBTop) {
        translateY = 0;
    } else if (e.pageY > sBBottom) {
        translateY = getHeight(scrollBar) - getHeight(thumb);
    } else {
        translateY = e.pageY - sBTop - .5 * getHeight(thumb);
    }
}

function followMe(e) {
    scrollLimited;
    thumb.style.transform = "translate3d(0," + translateY + "px,0)";
    document.getElementById('ejercicios').scrollTop = translateY * ratio;
    document.documentElement.addEventListener("mouseup", release, false);
}

function perform() {
    if (adentroBar === true) {
        translateY = e.pageY - sBTop - getHeight(thumb) / 2;
    }
    thumb.style.transform = "translate3d(0," + translateY + "px,0)";
    document.getElementById('ejercicios').scrollTop = translateY * ratio;
    document.documentElement.addEventListener("mousemove", followMe, false);
}

function release() {
    document.documentElement.removeEventListener("mousemove", followMe, false);
}

function checkAndPerform(e) {
    var translateY, adentroBar, scrollBar = document.getElementById('scrollbar'),
        thumb = scrollBar.getElementsByTagName("div")[0],
        sBLeft = scrollBar.getBoundingClientRect().left,
        sBRight = scrollBar.getBoundingClientRect().right,
        sBTop = scrollBar.getBoundingClientRect().top,
        sBBottom = scrollBar.getBoundingClientRect().bottom,
        preg = document.getElementById('preguntas'),
        ratio = preg.offsetHeight / (getHeight(scrollBar) - getHeight(thumb));
    if (e.which === 1) {
        checkClick;
        perform;
    }
}
document.documentElement.addEventListener("mousedown", checkAndPerform, false);
```

Also, here it is a jFiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/pa0exs4q/
I may provide the working code in case you find it interesting, but as i have said, it is really messy and porly written.
Problem is second function in flow (checkClick), is not even being called.
I have tried to call it as (checkClick(e)), in that case it runs, but fails to recognize variables defined above in checkAndPerform.
In my working code, everything was an only function, so i think it may be a scope problem, but I am open for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a function named `myFunction`, you can pass it around simply as `myFunction`, but to actually call it you have to write it as `myFunction()`.  So this:

```
function checkAndPerform(e){
  var translateY, adentroBar, scrollBar=document.getElementById('scrollbar'), thumb=scrollBar.getElementsByTagName("div")[0], sBLeft=scrollBar.getBoundingClientRect().left, sBRight=scrollBar.getBoundingClientRect().right, sBTop=scrollBar.getBoundingClientRect().top, sBBottom=scrollBar.getBoundingClientRect().bottom, preg=document.getElementById('preguntas'), ratio=preg.offsetHeight/(getHeight(scrollBar)-getHeight(thumb));    

  if (e.which===1){
    checkClick;
    perform;
  }
}
```

Should become this:

```
function checkAndPerform(e){
  var translateY, adentroBar, scrollBar=document.getElementById('scrollbar'), thumb=scrollBar.getElementsByTagName("div")[0], sBLeft=scrollBar.getBoundingClientRect().left, sBRight=scrollBar.getBoundingClientRect().right, sBTop=scrollBar.getBoundingClientRect().top, sBBottom=scrollBar.getBoundingClientRect().bottom, preg=document.getElementById('preguntas'), ratio=preg.offsetHeight/(getHeight(scrollBar)-getHeight(thumb));    

  if (e.which===1){
    checkClick(e);
    perform(e); // make sure to pass e and expect it in perform, otherwise it won't have access to it
  }
}
```

Without seeing your corresponding markup, this seems to me the most likely and glaring issue in your code.

Comment: After this i had to learn the difference between "pass" and "call", but as you said, it worked just after passing parameters to each function.. Except one.. :S. For that one i created an object with properties  and now its working great! Many thanks!